# How do you integrate $\displaystyle\int\sin(2x)\cos(x)\mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

Compute the following

$$\displaystyle\int\sin(2x)\cos(x)\mathrm dx$$

Can someone please show all the steps because my Professor solved it and I look at his work and there are a couple steps and I would really like to understand it profoundly. FYI I am not all that great with trig functions

Comment: Use the product to sum formulae

Comment: @nehalsharma: **Hint:** $\sin 2 x = 2 \sin x \cos x$. Let $u = \cos x$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: It would help if  you showed the steps and pointed out the parts you have difficulty with. Else you may get an answer identical to your prof's.

Answer (score 10):

$\displaystyle \int \sin (2x)\cos x dx$

$\displaystyle = \int 2\sin x \cos ^2 x dx$

Now substitute $u=\cos x$ then $du=-\sin x dx$

$\displaystyle \int 2 \sin x \cos ^2 x dx = -2 \int u^2 du$

$\displaystyle = -\frac {2u^3}3+C$

$\displaystyle = -\frac {2\cos ^3 x}3 +C$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int\sin(2x)\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\sin(2x-x)+\sin(2x+x)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\cos(x)-\frac{1}{3}\cos(3x)\right)+C
\end{align}$$